# Mouse not working (perrixx)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, mouse

My perrixx mx3000 lights up but it does not move.

Is there anyway to make it work? im stuck with my painfully broken mouse. I tried installing the drivers on the website but its only for windows.

first command
http://pastebin.com/yvGdWd02

second and third command
http://pastebin.com/jjnBNZqe

Comment: Hi, and welcome to askubuntu.com Can you edit your question and add the output of the following commands to it? `lsusb -v` and `uname -a` then unplug and plug your mouse and add the output of `dmesg | tail -n 20`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mouse is not supported by your current kernel.
If you are fine with changing to a newer kernel run this command:

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-saucy`

If you are not fine with that, aka, you are getting other issues you can not mange to solve with eg. graphic drivers. Is it still possible to get the mouse working with backporting of the driver module.

PS. You will need to reboot after the installation of the new kernel.

Comment: Whats the kernel do? will it do anything other then making the mouse work?

Comment: You can look at it this way, changing the kernel of a linux based system is the same as changing the engine for a car. The only difference is that you can keep both, and decide on boot which one to start. (That can be done from the grub menu, if you can't see it try to tap the Left-SHIFT on the keyboard during boot.) So the command is taking the Ubuntu 13.10 kernel and put it under the hood of your 12.04 Ubuntu. If something doesn't work is it just to start with the older kernel.

Comment: in the grub menu whats it suppsed to say because i cant boot into one of the ubuntu's i had to go to "older linux version"

Comment: So i boot up on grub says "linux with ubuntu 3.11.0-13" so i enter it and that gets stuck at the ubuntu screen. i pressed the arrow keys and it brought me to the debug menu and it seemed to stop at "stopping system V run level compatibility" so then i reboot and in grub there is a "previous linux" menu went into that and there is 3.8.0-33 and 3.8.0-29 and those 2 work which is what im on now

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8fvi0Zbu not sure if thats what you want

Comment: looks more like it i g2g for about an hour http://pastebin.com/EMfnGFBn

Comment: not installed do you want me to install it?

Comment: just says this:  libdrm-nouveau1a    install
libdrm-nouveau2     install
nvidia-319     install
nvidia-common     install
nvidia-prime     install
nvidia-settings-319    install
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-raring  install

Comment: still gives me the same error in 3.11.0-13 i installed the thing too

Comment: Error on the last command near the end http://pastebin.com/x7iASb6s

Comment: It Boots and better yet the mouse works!!! thanks alot sir. Buut one problem the graphics cards seems to not be working (games fps dropped quite a bit) should i just upgrade to 13.10 i just got ubuntu yesterday i dont have much on it. also the program to set the mouse dpi and colours should i run that in wine?

Comment: EDIT: on the additional drivers page there is some. nvidia binary xorge driver, kernel module and VDPAU should i get that?

Comment: Minecraft which is what im using to test this cause its like a 5mb game doesnt work anymmore. and in the error message i can see somthing to do with the display drivers. also since my mouse saves profiles and im going to be duel booting with windows ill just set all the mouse crap in windows

Comment: yes i did i installed the driveers

Comment: libdrm-nouveau1a    install
libdrm-nouveau2     install
nvidia-304     install
nvidia-current     install
nvidia-settings     install
nvidia-settings-304    install
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-raring  install

Comment: http://pastebin.com/aDUra1vx can you explain what you want some more i dont get it. and im fine with doing this if you got better stuff to do and dont have time i can upgrade to 13.10 and also isint jumping through hoops and doing very odd things to make something work slow down the system? im sure you have better stuff to do

Comment: no i meean explain moree on what to do i did not understand you instructions

Comment: okay sure how or what